# Does every diagonal matrix have an $r$ by $r$ invertible submatrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra 4th Edition* states, "Every diagonal matrix has an $r$ by $r$ invertible submatrix."

However, I don't think this is true in the case of any zero matrix, which are diagonal. Any $r$ by $r$ invertible submatrix of a zero matrix will also be a zero matrix, and as far as I know, a zero matrix is never invertible.

Am I missing something, or did Professor Strang simply ignore a trivial case in favor of conciseness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you left out something like "where $r$ is the rank of the matrix".  If the matrix is the zero matrix, its rank is $0$, and there is no such thing as a $0 \times 0$ matrix.